# The simplest way to rearrange a list using web tools

Tags: list, plaintext

I have the need for a web tool that would enable me to rearrange quickly a list that I would input in a field as plain text, and then rearrange the elements using drag and drop, and then export again in plain text.

I know it's easy to program but if this was already done in a simple web tool, I would be delighted.

Alexandre

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any pre made, dead simple tools for this, but most free todo list apps have this functionality. Trello, ToodleDo etc are good examples.